# Find url/ip of container running in docker-compose in gitlab ci

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, gitlab, containers

I have an application that runs in docker-compose (for acceptance testing).  The acceptance tests work locally, but they require the host (or ip) of the webservice container running in docker-compose in order to send requests to it.  This works fine locally, but I cannot find the ip of the container when it is running in a gitlab ci server.  I've tried the following few solutions (all of which work when running locally, but none of which work in gitlab ci) to find the url of the container running in docker-compose in gitlab ci server:

1. use "docker" as the host.  This works for an application running in docker, but not docker-compose
2. use docker-inspect to find the ip of the container (*docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' reading-comprehension*)
3. assign a static ip to the container using a network in docker-compose.yml (latest attempt).

The gitlab ci file can be found here:
https://gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension/-/blob/9-list-all-assessments/.gitlab-ci.yml

```
    image: connorbutch/gradle-and-java-11:alpha

variables:
  GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
  DOCKER_DRIVER: "overlay2"

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle

services:
  - docker:stable-dind

stages:
  - build
  - docker_build
  - acceptance_test

unit_test:
  stage: build
  script: ./gradlew check
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew clean quarkusBuild
    - ./gradlew clean build -Dquarkus.package.type=native -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    policy: push
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl/build/

docker_build:
  stage: docker_build
  script:
    - cd reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl
    - docker build -f infrastructure/Dockerfile -t registry.gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA  .
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA

acceptance_test:
  stage: acceptance_test
  only:
    - merge_requests
  script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - cd reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl/infrastructure
    - export IMAGE_TAG=$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    - docker-compose up -d & ../../wait-for-it-2.sh
    - cd ../..
    - ./gradlew -DBASE_URL='192.168.0.8' acceptanceTest
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - reading-comprehension/reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl/build/
```

The docker-compose file can be found here:
https://gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension/-/blob/9-list-all-assessments/reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl/infrastructure/docker-compose.yml

Find the output of one of the failed jobs here:
https://gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension/-/jobs/734771859

```
#This file is NOT ever intended for use in production.  Docker-compose is a great tool for running
#database with our application for acceptance testing.
version: '3.3'

networks:
  network:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.0.0/24

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.10
    container_name: "db"
    restart: always
    environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: "rc"
       MYSQL_USER: "user"
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: "password"
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
       MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
    networks:
      network:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.0.4
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
  reading-comprehension-ws:
    image: "registry.gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension:${IMAGE_TAG}"
    container_name: "reading-comprehension"
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: "db:3306"
      DB_USER: "user"
      DB_PASSWORD: "password"
      DB_JDBC_URL: "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.4:3306/rc"
    networks:
      network:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.0.8
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    expose:
      - 8080
volumes:
  db:
```

**Does anyone have any idea on how to access the ip of the container running in docker-compose on gitlab ci server?  Any suggestions are welcome.**

Thanks,

Connor

Comment: Probably, you may add acceptance tests to same docker-compose?

Comment: I see this IP address in your error message:
`level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.18.0.0/16 .`

Comment: Thank you for pointing this log out mdabdullah!  I will go ahead and rerun, attempting to assign my static ip to be in the subnet.  Do you happen to know (it is fine if you don't) if this range is always the same for a service running in docker-compose on gitlab-ci?  Additionally, do you know how I could use the --bip option in gitlab ci?  Thanks again

Comment: I assigned the same subnet as the one listed in the logs (and got a log message which seems to confirm this), and attempted to connect to this ip, however, it was still not available.  I believe the issue is that the docker-compose service runs on a different host entirely (for example, when running docker in docker, the host is "docker", but this doesn't work for docker compose).  Do you have any ideas on how to find this host?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is little bit tricky, just few days ago I had similar problem but with VPN from CI to client :)

## EDIT: Solution for on-premise gitlab instances

Create custom network for gitlab runners:

```
docker network create --subnet=172.16.0.0/28 \
 --opt com.docker.network.bridge.name=gitlab-runners \
 --opt com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc=true \
 --opt com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade=true \
 --opt com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4=0.0.0.0 \
 --opt com.docker.network.driver.mtu=9001 gitlab-runners
```

Attach new network to gitlab-runners

```
# /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
[[runners]]
....
   [runners.docker]
   ....
   network_mode = "gitlab-runners"
```

Restart runners.

And finally gitlab-ci.yml

```
start-vpn:
    stage: prepare-deploy
    image: docker:stable
    cache: {}
    variables:
        GIT_STRATEGY: none
    script:
        - >
            docker run -it -d --rm
            --name vpn-branch-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
            --privileged
            --net gitlab-runners
            -e VPNADDR=$VPN_SERVER
            -e VPNUSER=$VPN_USER
            -e VPNPASS=$VPN_PASSWORD
            auchandirect/forticlient || true && sleep 2
        - > 
            docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' 
            vpn-branch-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME > vpn_container_ip
    artifacts:
        paths:
        - vpn_container_ip
```

And in next step you can use something like:

```
before_script:
        - ip route add 10.230.163.0/24 via $(cat vpn_container_ip) # prod/dev
        - ip route add 10.230.164.0/24 via $(cat vpn_container_ip) # test
```

## EDIT: Solution for gitlab.com

Base on [gitlab issue answer](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/26566#note_200719034) port mapping in DinD is bit different from nonDinD gitlab-runner and for exposed ports you should use hostname 'docker'.

Example:

```
services:
  - docker:stable-dind

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"

stages:
  - test

test env:
  image: tmaier/docker-compose:latest
  stage: test
  script:
    # containous/whoami with exposed port 80:80
    - docker-compose up -d
    - apk --no-cache add curl
    - curl docker:80              # <------- 
    - docker-compose down
```

Comment: Thank you so much Facty!  I am using gitlab community, and do not have my own runner.  Is the above possible using the community runner (I don't believe I can use the toml file there)?

FYI: I upvoted the answer

Comment: Ah I never used "cloud" community version, always working with on-premise instance. But my guess is that you can achieve same result using DinD service because those DinD containers share same network as "master" container. And thanks for upvote :)

Comment: Thanks for the continued help Facty.  As you stated, I've been using the docker in docker service, and it works great (it allows me to run docker and docker compose).  I can even call the service when it is running in dind using the host 'docker', however, I cannot find the host for running the application on docker-compose.  Any ideas on how to find this?  I've tried localhost, docker, as well as assigning a static ip via a network in docker-compose, but I can't seem to get any of these to work.

Comment: After many failed attempts (what a pain :) ) solution found for dind: [PIPELINE](https://gitlab.com/facty/playground/-/jobs/740511731) Problem is how port mapping is handled in dind. You have to use hostname docker instead of anything else

Comment: Thanks Facty.  As mentioned earlier, I had been using docker host, and it had been working for applications running in "pure" docker.  However, I had tried this solution for applications running in docker-compose, and it does not look to be working.  Let me confirm again, but I am fairly certain that the hostname might be different.... (fingers crossed I made a typo or something)

Comment: Let me know about outcome

Comment: Thanks Facty; I tried again with the host being "docker", and it didn't seem to work for docker-compose.  See the logs here: https://gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension/-/jobs/742141523

Any ideas?