# Gitlab CI/CD: How to wget/curl an API endpoint of the current container

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am setting up an Gitlab CI/CD pipeline to test several Laravel micro services and an front-end. To check if the front-end displays the results from the API endpoints correctly I thought to pass it the results form the endpoints as artifacts.

I thought this would be simple, like doing something like

```yaml
after_script:
  ...
  - wget --no-check-certificate 'https://localhost/api/product/' -O ./artifacts/product_api.json

artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - ./artifacts/product_api.json
```

But I was wrong. Localhost is the server that starts the containers. So somehow I need to find out what is the Hostname or the IP of the container.

I found various place (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63864428/find-url-ip-of-container-running-in-docker-compose-in-gitlab-ci)) that claim the hostname is 'docker', yet I can't even ping that name.

[Anothers suggest I find](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/problem-using-curl-to-access-a-container-port-inside-a-dind-runner/35203) is using:

```yaml
  - CONTAINER_IP=$(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAdress}}{{end}}' myapp) // Replace myapp with your container name.
  - sleep 15
  - curl $CONTAINER_IP:8000
```

but this would require me to install Docker, which I would much rather not.

Is there a way to reach your current container in Gitlab CI/CD? (I am NOT self-hosting the runners)

My .gitlab-ci.yml looks something like:

```yaml
Product-API:
  image: serversideup/php:8.2-fpm-nginx
 
  services:
    - name: mysql:8.0.33-debian
      alias: mysql
      entrypoint: ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'sed -i -e "/^skip-name-resolve/d" /etc/mysql/conf.d/docker.cnf && /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld']
  
  variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
    GIT_SUBMODULE_FORCE_HTTPS: "true"
    #FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 1

    #mysql variables
    MYSQL_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    MYSQL_USER: $MYSQL_SHOP_ADMIN
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_SHOP_ADMIN_PASSWORD
    
    #laravel variables
    APP_DEBUG: "true"
    DB_CONNECTION: mysql
    DB_HOST: $MYSQL_HOST
    DB_PORT: 3306
    DB_USERNAME: '$PRODUCTAPI_DB_USER'
    DB_PASSWORD: '$PRODUCTAPI_DB_PASSWORD'
    DB_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE


  before_script:
    #download and unpack the product database
    - mkdir artifacts
    - 'curl --location --output ./artifacts/db_dump.zip --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $ARTIFACTS_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/test1/jobs/artifacts/develop/download?job=Database-Tables"'
    - 'curl --location --output ./artifacts/mysqlusersandgrants.zip --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $ARTIFACTS_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/test2/jobs/artifacts/develop/download?job=Database-Users"'
    - unzip ./artifacts/db_dump.zip    
    - unzip ./artifacts/mysqlusersandgrants.zip
 
    #put the database in place
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y mysql-client
    - mysql -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD --host=$MYSQL_HOST "$MYSQL_DATABASE" < ./artifacts/db_dump.sql
    - mysql -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD --host=$MYSQL_HOST mysql < ./artifacts/mysqlusersandgrants.sql

    #putting and .env file in place
    - mv .env.example .env
    #install Laravel
    - composer install
    - php artisan key:generate
    - php artisan config:cache
    - php artisan route:cache
    - php artisan view:cache
    #setting user and group rights
    - chown -R webuser:webgroup .

  script:
     - php artisan test --log-junit productapi_results.xml

  after_script:
    - 'curl -k --location --output ./artifacts/product_api.json "https://docker/api/product/"'
    - cat ./artifacts/product_api.json

  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - ./artifacts/product_api.json
      - productapi_results.xml
    reports:
      junit: productapi_results.xml
```

This gives the error:

```
Running after script...
$ curl -k --location --output ./artifacts/product_api.json "https://docker/api/product/"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: docker
[18-Jan-2024 20:19:43] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[18-Jan-2024 20:19:43] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
WARNING: after_script failed, but job will continue unaffected: exit code 1
```

Comment: What application is supposed to host endpoint `/api/product/`? Did you started it? Claims about `docker` as hostname are true if you are using service `- docker:stable-dind` you only have `mysql` service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find where you start the web server, thus added that too:

- Should serve in background to keep continue. That's why `&` is added.
- Waiting a little is probably good idea, thus `sleep 10`.

```yaml
  script:
    - php artisan test --log-junit productapi_results.xml
    - php artisan serve --port=8000 &
    - sleep 10
    - curl http://localhost:8000/api/product/ --output ./artifacts/product_api.json
```

You can't use `after_script` to make request to your web server that runs in `script` phase:

- It runs after that script is completed, if you start a web server it won't complete (fail or success).
- It's in separate shell, your changes won't be here.

From doc:

> Don’t have access to changes done by commands defined in the before_script or script, including:
> Command aliases and variables exported in script scripts.
> Changes outside of the working tree (depending on the runner executor), like software installed by a before_script or script script.

---

To make things clear below is minimal reproducible example:

```yaml
dep:
  image: nginx:latest
  script:
    - nginx -g 'daemon off;' 2>&1 > /dev/null & 
    - curl http://localhost > product_api.json
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths: 
      - product_api.json
```

Answer (score 2):

"Could not resolve host: docker"? I have only seen '`docker`' as a hostname when accessing the [docker registry hostname](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#docker-no-such-host-error), where the shorter service hostname `docker` is expected.

In GitLab CI/CD, especially when not self-hosting runners, the hostname `docker` does not necessarily point to the current running container or any service within the CI job. That hostname might not be recognized in the GitLab-managed runners' environment.

In your case, the Laravel application is accessible to the curl command within the same container, using localhost as the hostname and 8000 as the port number.

```bash
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| GitLab CI/CD Runner                                       |
| +-------------------------------------------------------+ |
| | CI Job Container                                      | |
| |                                                       | |
| | +---------------------------------------------------+ | |
| | | Laravel Application (Product-API)                 | | |
| | | - Served on localhost:8000                        | | |
| | +---------------------------------------------------+ | |
| |                                                       | |
| | +---------------------------------------------------+ | |
| | | Curl Command                                      | | |
| | | - Accessing Laravel App via http://localhost:8000 | | |
| | +---------------------------------------------------+ | |
| +-------------------------------------------------------+ |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

You have used `https` in your `curl` command. Make sure your Laravel application is set up to handle HTTPS requests. If it is not configured for HTTPS, you should use `http` instead (so no `-k` option needed).

Since your Laravel application and the `curl` command are executed within the same CI job (and hence, within the same container), you should be able to use `localhost` to access your application. That means the URL in your `curl` command should be `http://localhost:8000/api/product/` if you are using the default HTTP port 8000.

Make sure the port you are using in the `curl` command matches the port on which your Laravel application is running. If you are using the default Laravel port (8000), then `localhost:8000` is correct. If you have configured a different port, adjust the `curl` command accordingly.

Make sure the Laravel server is running when you execute the `curl` command. As mentioned in the previous response, you can start the Laravel server in the background during the `script` phase of your CI/CD pipeline.

Your `.gitlab-ci.yml` would be:

```yaml
  script:
    - php artisan serve --port=8000 &
    - sleep 10 # Wait for the server to start
    - curl http://localhost:8000/api/product/ --output ./artifacts/product_api.json
```

Comment: Hi thx for your reply, all you say seems true! My app runs on https:// though in this case. The after_script seemed to be the problem. Since Umut was first I'll give him the points. Thxz again

Comment: @St.Jan Great, well done. I did upvote Umut's answer.